# Angular 2 RC 5 router

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

The main issue was that in my AuthService (which I injected in AppComponent)  had injected Router, which is provided to the loaded Module, which causes this error.I removed it from Auth Service and left it in my AppComponent, so at least one component is loaded first.

I'm currently try to figure out how does new version of angular works.
I'm getting the error:

> Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router.

My app.module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {routing, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, children } from './app.routes';

import {appStateProvider} from './providers/AppStateProvider'
// Import configured routes
import {AuthGuard} from './services/auth.guard'
import {AuthService} from './services/auth.service';
import {AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './components/login.component'
import {HomeComponent} from './components/home.component'


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing,
        children

      ],
       providers: [
        appStateProvider, 
        APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        AuthService,
        InsaService
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        NewsComponent
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

main.ts file:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and app component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core'
import { Router,Routes,
         NavigationExtras, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {AuthService} from  './services/auth.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private authenticated: boolean = false;
  private loginSubscriber;

  constructor(private _appStateProvider: appStateProvider, private _authService: AuthService, private _insaService: InsaService, private _router:Router) {
    console.log("AppComponent logged")
    if (this._authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this._router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
    else {
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginSubscriber = this._authService.LoggedInStatusChangedEmitter.subscribe(
      (loggedin) => {
        this.authenticated = loggedin.value;
      }
    );
  }

  logout(sender: any) {
    this._authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.loginSubscriber.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I updated app to RC5 and followed documentation but don't know what caused the error.

Comment: I believe the problem is within AuthGuard, where you inject the Router. Same issue here. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: Hi! I updated my answer, please check :)

Comment: Didn't got your answer clearly, could you please clarify your solution please

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue after upgrading from RC4 to RC5. It was caused by including components in the routing providers array.

```
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [
    SomeComponent <-- don't do this!  
];

export const appRouterModule = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Small tip: Try to implement some Feature Modules to clean up your code. Makes it a little easier to debug your code. You can read more about feature modules in: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issues with your `app.module.ts` file. I expect this is caused by useing `appRoutingProviders` rather than `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` if you are taking your approach.

```
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, homeComponent, /* etc... */ ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders // <- this is what you were missing
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: No, I forgot to share my app.routes.ts file, it uses: export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS : any[]= [
  AuthGuard
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

Comment: Oh I see ... ignore that then. Another difference I have spotted (not sure if it is important), but in NgModule, the examples usually have declarations above providers, have you tried that?

Comment: No, it's not. I'm so pissed off with all those breaking changes Angular team  did in RC versions of A2 :(

Comment: Yeh, it's super annoying. Sorry - I don't know what else to suggest. I am currently using RC5  in a project and the v3 router (RC1) is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but you can try the below.

**app.module**

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { appRouterProviders } from "./app.routes";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import { SidenavComponent } from './sidenav.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        SidenavComponent           
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [appRouterProviders]
})

export class AppModule {
    constructor(private _appRef: ApplicationRef) { }

    ngDoBootstrap() {
        this._appRef.bootstrap(AppComponent);
    }
}
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MyComponent } from "./my.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/my',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'my',
        component: MyComponent
    }
];

export const appRouterProviders = provideRouter(routes);
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Why we have to redirect from `path:''` to somewhere? How can we make `path: ''` to use component `AppComponent`?

Comment: Something like this: {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/app',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'app',
        component: AppComponent
    }

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, the problem was injecting Router into constructor of some existing components, removed the injection and error went away.  Try following the stack trace shown in the console to see if you can identify which component it is complaining about.  This error occurred while attempting to instantiate a service provider that was injecting Router into constructor, in my case.

Comment: And what if you actually need that injection?

Comment: My service had injected Router in constructor and that caused the error. Injecting Router in other component doesn't cause the errir since AppCpmponent is bootstraped since then. :)